# Apache Solr integration with Salesforce

Tags: search

I want to integrate 'Apache Solr' search functionality in 'Salesforce'.
Is there any option to include solr search with salesforce?

Comment: Not aware of Apache Solr but a quick google search gives this link: http://www.grazitti.com/blog/improve-salesforce-search-using-solr/ See if this work for you. Also, it would be good if you can detailed out the reason for using Apache Solr.

Comment: Thanks for you reply!! But I am seeking for solr integration with salesforce.

Comment: I am trying to integrate as well , but getting an error summary field on solr server is text area, but salesforce created field is text area so, not able to complete the data sync, Thanks,
Samuel

Answer (score 1):

I've used Solr successfully to make Salesforce data searchable. It was needed, because the search capabilities of SFDC were poor. We used it to perform searches within the collection of the customers

You can create a standalone Solr-based application, where you can index any data you want. Then you build an API on top of this application, and use it wherever you need.